# How to model a bounded lognormal dependent variable with many zeros

Tags: regression, generalized-linear-model, econometrics, censoring, tobit-regression

I try to analyze firms´ investment decisions.
In my dataset 70% of the firms choose to invest 0 $ .
30% invest more than 0. (continuous variable).
The data of the 30 % is log normally distributed.

Which model is recommended for such data structure? OLS, tobit or glm model? Or even something else?

First I thought a Tobit model would be appropriate but I then I gave up this idea due to the log 0 problem.

Comment: You might want to mention that you're working with panel data, if that is still the case. This both complicates the problem, but may allow you to estimate this.

Answer (score 3):

You could model this as a zero inflated gamma (or zero inflated log normal), where you assume two process - one that generates zero with a certain probability (those that dont invest) and for those that do, a process that follows a gamma (or could use log normal).

I have used this model several times, writing contrast statements as Dale shows in the link below for E(Y). It is very useful. I wont go into more detail because the link sums up most of the salient points.

Here is a link to the code for fitting this model in [SAS](http://listserv.uga.edu/cgi-bin/wa?A2=ind0805A&L=sas-l&P=R20779). The question was posed on this site about converting to [R](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/15577/convert-sas-nlmixed-code-for-zero-inflated-gamma-regression-to-r), without a definitive answer, but I am sure it is possible.

Another option is to use two separate models P(Y=0) and E(Y | y>0) and make inference about E(Y) with simulation (page of 150 of [Gelman, Hill 2007](http://books.google.com/books?id=c9xLKzZWoZ4C&printsec=frontcover#v=onepage&q=compound%20models&f=false)).